# Find recursive formula for sequence $a_n = \left(\frac23\right)^n + n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

So I start with:  $$a_n = \left(\frac23\right)^n + n$$
I know $a_1=\frac53, a_2=\frac{22}9, a_3=\frac{340}{81}, a_4=\frac{1247}{243} $
Then I do:
$$a_{n-1} = \left(\frac23\right)^{n-1} + (n-1)$$

Do I now do $a_n - a_{n-1}$ or $a_n\over a_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: Try both... Go with whatever is nicer and if neither work, look for a different pattern.

Comment: @John-Wayland-Bales thanks nice catch I updated.

Comment: No problem. I will delete the comment.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 4):

You already know that $$a_n-a_{n-1}=\left(\frac23\right)^n + n-\left(\frac23\right)^{n-1} - (n-1)=-\frac12\left(\frac23\right)^n+1$$ but, as explained about an answer to a previous question of yours, this is not a recursion relation since the RHS still depends on $n$. To remedy this, introduce $$b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$$ If one can find a recursion formula for $(b_n)$, the exercise will be solved, right? And look, by definition, $$b_n=-\frac12\left(\frac23\right)^n+1$$ hence $$b_{n-1}=-\frac12\left(\frac23\right)^{n-1}+1$$ And $b_n$ is almost $\frac23$ times $b_{n-1}$.

To transform "almost" into "exactly", consider $$c_n=b_n-1$$ then $$c_n=-\frac12\left(\frac23\right)^n$$ and for *this* sequence, a recursion is easy, which reads $$c_n=\frac23\cdot c_{n-1}$$ Now it remains to come back to $(a_n)$, which is done in two steps, first by noting that $c_n=b_n-1$ hence $$b_n-1=\frac23\cdot (b_{n-1}-1)$$ and then by noting that $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ hence $$a_n-a_{n-1}-1=\frac23\cdot (a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}-1)$$ which after a bit of massaging is equivalent to

> $$3a_n-5a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}=1$$

Of course, the fact that the linear combination one arrives at corresponds to the polynomial $$3x^2-5x+2$$ whose roots are $$x=1\qquad x=\frac23$$ is no coincidence, but explaining *that* might be best kept for another question...

Comment: Clever approach (just to add the initial conditions)

Answer (score 3):

Presumably they want you to find a recursive formula of a certain form, the most commonly taught form being a linear combination of previous terms.  If any form was acceptable then you could just write $a_n = (2/3)^n + n + a_{n - 1} - a_{n - 1}$.

A matrix with the behavior you want is the Jordan matrix $$M^n = \begin{bmatrix} 2/3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^n$$

which implies that there is some recursions of the form

$$a_{n + 3} = X~a_{n+2} + Y~a_{n + 1} + Z~a_{n}$$

that satisfies your equation.  So solving

$$\begin{cases} 
a_5 = X a_4 + Y a_3 + Z a_2 \\
a_4 = X a_3 + Y a_2 + Z a_1 \\
a_3 = X a_2 + Y a_1 + Z a_0 \\
\end{cases}$$

with your initial conditions gets a solution.  I suggest working it out on your own, after you can hover over below to check your solution:

> $$\begin{align} X = 8/3,~Y=-7/3,~Z=2/3 \\ \\ 3~a_{n+3} = 8~a_{n+2} - 7~a_{n+1} + 2~a_{n} \end{align}$$

Comment: Btw, alternatively, if you didn't know about jordan forms, you could just test linear equations of increasing size until you found one.  You can check your guess (of the degree of the equation) by plugging the initial equation into the final equation and seeing if it is a tautology.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right to try and find $a_n-a_{n-1}$. If we work it out, then we have
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^n-\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}+n-n+1$$
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=\frac{2}{3}\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}-\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}+1$$
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=-\frac{1}{3}\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}+1$$
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^n+1$$
$$a_n=a_{n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^n+1$$

One way to find recursive formulas given explicit ones that might work in future problems is to use the following formula:
If
$$a_n=f(n)$$
then
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=f(n)-f(n-1)$$
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+f(n)-f(n-1)$$
and that should do it. You could even take the ratio approach that you mentioned:
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{f(n)}{f(n-1)}$$
$${a_n}=\frac{f(n)a_{n-1}}{f(n-1)}$$
Does this help?

Comment: in line 3 why $-\frac13\times(\frac23)^{n-1}+1$?

Comment: We have $\frac{2}{3}x-x=-\frac{1}{3}x$, where $x$ is $\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}$

Comment: sorry for sounding pedantic but how is $-\frac13$ a common factor (is that the right terminology)?

Comment: I didn't do any factoring, except to pull out the $\frac{2}{3}$. If you have some number $x$, then the value of $\frac{2}{3}x-x$ is $-\frac{1}{3}x$. Thus the value of $\frac{2}{3}\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}-\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}$ is $-\frac{1}{3}\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Also, why the down vote? Anything you want me to improve with my answer?

Comment: I didn't down vote but I did just upvote! Thanks for the explanation though. Now the next line with the $\frac12$ has me scratching my head.

Comment: The phrase "recursion relation" is usually ttaken as referring to a formula $$F(a_n,a_{n-1},\ldots,a_{n-k})=0$$ for some fixed $k$ and some function $F$ independent of $n$. The relation you suggest is not of this form.

Comment: @Did Did the OP ask for a "recursion relation"? The question title uses the words "recursive formula".

Comment: @Kydd $$\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^n$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{n-1}$$

Comment: @Nilknarf ?? Please replace the former by the latter in my comment. Isn't this obvious?

Comment: @Kydd Do you understand now?

Comment: @Nilknarf Actually your whole post is quite misleading...

Comment: @Did Can we move this conversation to chat? I would like to discuss why exactly you find it misleading, but this comment thread is long enough already. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60485/discussion-between-nilknarf-and-did).

Comment: @Nilknarf Please see comment to DanielV on other answer.

Answer (score 2):

The "straigth-on" approach is to take some progressive finite differences
and then decide on that basis the strategy.

In your case
$$
\eqalign{
  & a_{\,n}  = \left( {{2 \over 3}} \right)^{\,n}  + n  \cr 
  & \Delta a_{\,n}  = a_{\,n + 1}  - a_{\,n}  = 1 - {1 \over 3}\left( {{2 \over 3}} \right)^{\,n}   \cr 
  & \Delta ^2 a_{\,n}  = a_{\,n + 2}  - 2a_{\,n + 1}  + a_{\,n}  = {1 \over 9}\left( {{2 \over 3}} \right)^{\,n}  \cr} 
$$

then we can cancel the dependence from $(2/3)^n$ by expressing $ \Delta a_{\,n} $ in terms of $ \Delta^2 a_{\,n} $
$$
a_{\,n + 1}  - a_{\,n}  = 1 - 3\left( {a_{\,n + 2}  - 2a_{\,n + 1}  + a_{\,n} } \right)
$$

to conclude that
$$
3a_{\,n}  - 5a_{\,n - 1}  + 2a_{\,n - 2}  - 1 = 0\quad \left| \; \right.a_{\,0}  = 1,\;a_{\,1}  = 5/3
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle a_n=\bigg(\frac 23\bigg)^n+n$

Let's have $b_n=a_n-n$, it is immediate that $b_n$ verifies $b_{n+1}=\frac 23 b_n\iff 3b_{n+1}=2b_n$

Now if we set $c_n=3a_{n+1}-2a_n=\underbrace{3b_{n+1}-2b_n}_0+3(n+1)-2(n)=n+3$

We have $c_{n+1}-c_n=1$.

This equation once developed gives :

$3a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}-3a_{n+1}+2a_n=1\iff 3a_{n+2}-5a_{n+1}+2a_n=1$